# Where are Firefox versions stored?

Tags: firefox, version, windows-xp-sp3

How can I find all the installed versions of Firefox browser on Windows XP ? Is there, for example,  a special windows registry key where all the versions are stored ? I need this information in order to code a program that tells me what are these installed versions on my Windows XP. I am not asking you to code the program for me, I just ask where I can find that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some registry keys accessible under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla

Comment: I checked on my Windows XP but I found: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles (there is no Profiles entry)

Comment: Well I made some mistake. Here is the path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Mozilla\\{product}\\bin\\firefox.exe  and you can read version of the executable by the help of some API.

Comment: that gives me the path where firefox.exe is located.